# Load a local file in Chrome extension (not in same folder)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension allows users to set their own background image on the extension's page. It's completely cool with online files being used; however, it gives me this `Not allowed to load local resource: <file name>` when using an image somewhere on their computer. Is there a manifest option or something else I'm overlooking to allow this?

I have already tried using the checkbox for "Allow access to file URLs"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing you may want to try is setting the `file:///*` permission in `manifest.json` (it is a little buried in the [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)):

```
"permissions": [
    "file:///*"
],
```

I remember running across a similar issue before and this was the cause. Happy to troubleshoot further if this doesn't solve it.

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but I realize now I had used the content_script permission, not the general permission.

Comment: @Rhyono Yeah, I'd be lying if I said that stuff never tripped me up. Usually I just mash buttons until it works :)

Comment: I just tried to upload the extension and learned that I am not allowed to use the file access permission. Your answer is still entirely correct, but do you know of any other workaround or reason as to why that is?

Comment: @Rhyono I am not 100% sure, but I took a quick read through this thread (http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iaLuAtjbWpQ) and it seems like you may need approval first (since accessing user files is an issue, I'd imagine). I'll keep doing some digging and let you know if I find anything.